# How to show file directories in a web browser?

Tags: java, file, file-io

I want to display all the file directories in a web browser.

In java, I have coded it like this...

```
        File file = new File(directory);
        File[] fileList = folder.listFiles();
        for(int i=0; i<fileList.length; i++){
            if(fileList[i].isFile()){
                System.out.println("File " + fileList[i].getName());
            }
            else if(listOfFiles[i].isDirectory()){
                System.out.println("Directory " + fileList[i].getName());
            }
        }
```

It works and prints to a terminal, however, how would I go about displaying it in a browser? What method replaces the System.out.println()?

Comment: Is it server directory? Are you talking about web application?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one (This is a code segment of a `Servlet`)

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse servletResponse)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

      BufferedWriter bufferWriter = new BufferedWriter(servletResponse.getWriter());

      bufferWriter.write("any string");
}
```

In `Servlet` you have `HttpServletResponse`. Use

```
PrintWriter pw = servletResponse.getWriter();
```

to write on the client (browser) stream.